# Creating time plan based on start and end time and value per hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query that gives me a general information about incoming work:

```
  Start               End    ToPack
 2016-04-07 10:00     14:00  40
 2016-04-07 16:00     20:00  80
  ...
```

It is easy to count that I have to pack 10 units per hours between 10 - 14 and 20 units per hour between 16-20. I'd like to be able to present it in a table like this:

```
TIME     ToPack   
10:00    10
11:00    10
12:00    10
...
16:00    20
17:00    20
...
etc
```

I've been trying to do it using CTE but so far I've failed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a [table of numbers](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html) and `CROSS APPLY`.

Table of numbers is simply a table that has one column with integer numbers from 1 to some large enough number, say, 100,000. I personally use table with 100K numbers. Aaron Bertrand wrote a [good article](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) explaining how to generate such table.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (StartDT datetime2(0), EndDT datetime2(0), ToPack float);
INSERT INTO @T (StartDT, EndDT, ToPack) VALUES
('2016-04-07 10:00:00', '2016-04-07 14:00:00', 40),
('2016-04-07 16:00:00', '2016-04-07 20:00:00', 80);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM
    @T AS T
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            DATEADD(hour, dbo.Numbers.Number-1, T.StartDT) AS HourDT
            , T.ToPack / DATEDIFF(hour, T.StartDT, T.EndDT) AS ToPackPerHour
        FROM dbo.Numbers
        WHERE dbo.Numbers.Number <= DATEDIFF(hour, T.StartDT, T.EndDT)
    ) AS CA
ORDER BY HourDT;
```

**Result**

```
+---------------------+---------------------+--------+---------------------+---------------+
|       StartDT       |        EndDT        | ToPack |       HourDT        | ToPackPerHour |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------+---------------------+---------------+
| 2016-04-07 10:00:00 | 2016-04-07 14:00:00 |     40 | 2016-04-07 10:00:00 |            10 |
| 2016-04-07 10:00:00 | 2016-04-07 14:00:00 |     40 | 2016-04-07 11:00:00 |            10 |
| 2016-04-07 10:00:00 | 2016-04-07 14:00:00 |     40 | 2016-04-07 12:00:00 |            10 |
| 2016-04-07 10:00:00 | 2016-04-07 14:00:00 |     40 | 2016-04-07 13:00:00 |            10 |
| 2016-04-07 16:00:00 | 2016-04-07 20:00:00 |     80 | 2016-04-07 16:00:00 |            20 |
| 2016-04-07 16:00:00 | 2016-04-07 20:00:00 |     80 | 2016-04-07 17:00:00 |            20 |
| 2016-04-07 16:00:00 | 2016-04-07 20:00:00 |     80 | 2016-04-07 18:00:00 |            20 |
| 2016-04-07 16:00:00 | 2016-04-07 20:00:00 |     80 | 2016-04-07 19:00:00 |            20 |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------+---------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Brilliant! I've started experimenting with creating loops but this solution is so much simpler and faster!

Answer (score 0):

As a variation on @Vladimir's excellent solution, I can propose one using the very convenient [generate_series](http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/sql_server_blog/86/generate_series-for-sql-server-2008) function.

**Sample Data** *(using your data exactly, in text format)*:

```
CREATE TABLE #ToPack (StartDT char(16), EndT char(5), ToPack int);
INSERT INTO #ToPack VALUES ('2016-04-07 10:00', '14:00', 40);
INSERT INTO #ToPack VALUES ('2016-04-07 16:00', '20:00', 80);
```

**Query** *(Result as you proposed)*:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(tp.StartDT, 1, 10) AS [Date],
       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20), s.date_hour, 120), 12, 5) AS TimeSlot,
       s.ToPackSlot
FROM (
  SELECT *, CONVERT(datetime, StartDT) AS date_start,
         CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(11), StartDT)+EndT) AS date_end
  FROM #ToPack
  ) tp
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT DATEADD(hour, g.IntValue, tp.date_start) AS date_hour,
         tp.ToPack / DATEDIFF(hour, tp.date_start, tp.date_end) AS ToPackSlot
  FROM generate_series(1, DATEDIFF(hour, tp.date_start, tp.date_end), 1) g) s
```

Comment: That `generate_series` function may be convenient, but it can and should be implemented in much more efficient way than inserting row-by-row into a temporary table in a WHILE loop.

Comment: @Vladimir, the results of `generate_series` are intended to be dynamic, so ultimately they'd always be produced in some form of loop. True that TSQL is not very efficient for extensive loops. it took 14 seconds to run `select count(*) from generate_series(1, 1000000, 1)` on my server, whilst it took 0.3 seconds to run in PostgreSQL because it is coded in C, although the code is pretty much the same. I think the convenience of this function for small sets like this is great, although its performance can be increased via `Numbers` table (which can be generated with generate_series() ;-) ).

Comment: [This article](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) by Aaron Bertrand shows several methods for generating a set of rows. There are definitely ways to generate 1M rows within a fraction of a second in T-SQL. Table of numbers is just one of them.